# BIRT - how to set dynamic "Display text" for report parameter?

Tags: parameter-passing, birt

How can I dynamically set "Display text" property of report parameter?

Comment: Do you mean "Display name" or "Prompt text" or something else? Why do you need to set this dynamically (it might be impossible and you might have to find another solution)?

Answer (score 2):

What do you exactly mean by "display text" of a parameter. Are you refering to the "Selected display value" from a combobox or a listbox parameter? If so, you can use a scripted DS and generate the display values in the fetch method.

Comment: ...or use column from normal DS. Or any expression you like. ("Selection list values" -> "Dynamic" -> ...)

Answer (score 1):

He's talking about the parameter displayText, I think he meant either this:

```
params["name"].displayText
```

aka:

```
reportContext.getParameterDisplayText("name")
```

You could try something similar to this:

```
var javaString = (new Packages.java.lang.String(param["name"].displayText));
```

`javaString.replace("old_value", "new_value ");`